# Convert C++ Dictionary to Hashtable

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, hashtable

I create a function to convert Map to jobject in JNI 
and send this jobject to JAVA...

it's fine to boolean, but string and integer will crash....
Why does process crash at string and integer?

```
typedef Map<std::string, AbObj> Dictionary;

jobject Dictionary2jobject(JNIEnv *env, Dictionary* pDictionary)
{
    jclass class_Hashtable=env->FindClass("java/util/Hashtable");
    jmethodID construct_method=env->GetMethodID( class_Hashtable, "<init>","()V");
    jobject objMap = env->NewObject(class_Hashtable, construct_method, "");
    jmethodID add_method= env->GetMethodID(class_Hashtable,"put","(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    for(Dictionary::const_iterator it = pDictionary->begin(); it != pDictionary->end(); ++it)
    {
        switch(it->second.GetType())
        {
        case AbObj::OT_NIL:
            return NULL;
        case AbObj::OT_STR:
            {
                env->CallObjectMethod(objMap, add_method, env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str()), env->NewStringUTF(it->second.data._str));
            }
            break;
        case AbObj::OT_BLN:
            {
                env->CallObjectMethod(objMap, add_method, env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str()), (jboolean)it->second.data._bln);
            }
            break;
        case AbObj::OT_S32:     //int32_t
            {
                env->CallObjectMethod(objMap, add_method, env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str()), (jint)999);
            }
            break;
        case AbObj::OT_S64:     //int64_t
            {
                env->CallObjectMethod(objMap, add_method, env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str()), (jdouble)it->second.data._s64);
            }
            break;
    }
}
return objMap;
```

}

Comment: Do the expressions that deliver the value fourth argument work by themselves? i.e. before you call `CallObjectMethod()?`

Comment: Yes, all of values is correct..

Comment: Are you sure you've isolated the correct success cases? I would have thought that all the cases where you're passing a primitive would fail, and all the cases where you're passing an object such as a String would succeed. If that's so, there's a large hint right there.